# Help me find the logical mistake in this reasoning

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

We want to describe the set of solutions $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^+ : x^y = y^x\}$. To do that, we will construct a chain of equivalences:

\begin{align*}
x^y = y^x &\Leftrightarrow x^{\frac{y}{x}} = y \\
x^y = y^x &\Leftrightarrow \ln(x^y) = \ln(y^x) \Leftrightarrow y\ln(x) = x\ln(y).
\end{align*}

From this, it follows that

\begin{align*}
x^y = y^x \Leftrightarrow (x^{\frac{y}{x}} = y \land y\ln(x) = x\ln(y)) \Leftrightarrow y\ln(x) = x\ln(x^{\frac{y}{x}}) \Leftrightarrow y\ln(x) = y\ln(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{truth}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, the equivalence $x^y = y^x \Leftrightarrow \text{truth}$ holds, hence all pairs $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfy this equation. But clearly, this is not true, so I made a mistake somewhere. Could you help me find it? Thanks. :)

Comment: Please don't anyhow use tags... This isn't [tag:logic] at all.

Comment: @user21820 I think this definitely is logic. More specifically, variable introduction. I thought about tagging my question as analysis, but this wouldn't be faithful to its substance.

Comment: No. You clearly did not read the tag description. Please do not argue about something as indisputable as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

$$\forall x,y\quad  \text{true} \Rightarrow (x^{y/x} = y\quad \mbox{and}\quad x\ln y = y\ln x) $$
is false. In other words,

$$(x^{\frac{y}{x}} = y \land y\ln(x) = x\ln(y)) \Leftrightarrow y\ln(x) = x\ln(x^{\frac{y}{x}}) $$
works from left to right but not conversely.

Comment: Yep, the variable introduction going from right to left was the problem. :) Thank you. Although it would be interesting to see the deeper problem of introducing variables which are already present.